# how to make a Input/Output Error example?

Tags: error-handling

I'm working on a simple game console for raspberry pi, and I want to handle some common errors like segmentation fault, arithmetic exception and input/output error (since there maybe some guys using horrible SD cards).

when handler program detect the return code of my game, just show the corresponding error message on monitor.

I can easily test my handler by accessing null pointer or doing division by zero to trigger segmentation fault and arithmetic exception. But how to write a test program to trigger input/output error?

Comment: You seem to be confusing apples and pumpkins.  Segmentation fault and arithmetic exception are *signals* that, by default, cause the process to terminate in a characteristic way.  Input/output errors are just result codes that a program can ignore, or can handle in any way.  For example, `cat file1 file2` and ``grep pattern file1 file2`` issue an error message if `file1` does not exist, but they go on to process `file2`.  (They ultimately exit with error status codes.)  Bash doesn’t care if `~/.bashrc` doesn’t exist.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  There’s no way for a parent process to know that a child process has encountered an I/O error (except by tracing it).  The best you can do is check the exit status when it terminates, and different programs use different exit codes to mean different things.  If I’m misunderstanding what you’re asking for, please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.